# Simple DIV-Layout: Header, Navigation, Content

Tags: css, html, layout

I'm looking for the classic page layout:

Header 800 Pixel, Navi (left) 200 Pixel, Content (right) 600 Pixel

Is it possible to put this in 3 DIVs only?

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="navi">Navi</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```

Because every layout I've found so far is built this way:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="panel">
    <div id="navi">Navi</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div> <!-- position absolute left:200px -->
</div>
```

Thanks!
Roman

Comment: Are you willing to wrap the header, navigation and content in a wrapper block element?  Do you want to have the navi-content centered within the page?

Answer (score 0):

You surely can do it the way you told.

The thing is that code :

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="panel">
  <div id="navi">Navi</div>
  <div id="content">Content</div> <!-- position absolute left:200px -->
</div>
```

Will be easier to make and maintain. For example, you just need to specify a single margin-top on #panel to control margin between header and nav+content. With your code, you'll have to specify it twice, on #navi and on #content.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's too complex-- just set the header to width 100%. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/ASy67/

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
}
#header {
    background: #f00;
    width: 100%;
}
#left {
    background: #0f0;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#right {
    background: #f0f;
    width: 600px;
}
```

With this example, the content does appear behind the left sidebar. You can fix it by either adding `float: right;` to the `#right`, or `padding-left: 200px;` to `#right`.